# If $f:[0,t]\to[0,t]$ is continuous and increasing, why can we conclude $f(0)=0$ and $f(t)=t$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Let $t\ge0$ and $f:[0,t]\to[0,t]$ be continuous and (strictly) increasing. Why can we conclude $f(0)=0$ and $f(t)=t$?

I've tried the obvious thing: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ is increasing and right-continuous at $0$, there is a $\delta>0$ with $$0\le f(s)-f(0)<\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }s\in[0,\delta).\tag1$$ In $(1)$, I've used all the information we've got, but I don't see why this allows to conclude $f(0)<\varepsilon$ ...

Comment: Are you also assuming $f$ is surjective?

Comment: In what context did you encounter this statement?

Comment: @Ian Isn't for a continuous function between closed intervals bijectivity equivalent to strict monotonicity? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_on_Closed_Interval_is_Bijective_iff_Strictly_Monotone

Comment: @Arthur It is claimed (for $t=1$) here: https://books.google.com/books?id=6ItqtwaWZZQC&pg=RA2-PR10&lpg=RA2-PR10&dq=%22denote+the+class+of+strictly+increasing,+continuous+mappings%22&source=bl&ots=0LAeJzHoRK&sig=ACfU3U0DsMjj7uSIbONjQFJ0qljpAoCPNA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjr9PhnuvgAhWNJlAKHSF2Cj0Q6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22denote%20the%20class%20of%20strictly%20increasing%2C%20continuous%20mappings%22&f=true

Comment: You've missed a key word in that paragraph: "onto". That means we're looking at _surjective_ functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With those conditions, we *can't* conclude that. For instance, take $t=1$ and $f(x)=\frac12x+\frac14$. Then $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, but $f(0)=\frac14$ and $f(1)=\frac34$.

Seeing the new information, the exact quote is as follows (emphasis mine):

> Let $\Lambda$ denote the class of strictly increasing, continuous mappings of $[0,1]$ **onto** itself. If $\lambda\in\Lambda$, then $\lambda0 = 0$ and $\lambda1 = 1$.

The word "onto" here means that we only consider the mappings which are surjective. And a *surjective*, strictly increasing, continuous function $f:[0,t]\to[0,t]$ certainly has $f(0) = 0$ and $f(t) = t$.

Comment: Please take note of my comment below the question. Which assumption are we missing?

Comment: Isn't for a continuous function between closed intervals bijectivity equivalent to strict monotonicity (and hence our continuous increasing $f$ automatically bijective)? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_on_Closed_Interval_is_Bijective_iff_Strictly_Monotone

Comment: @0xbadf00d Once again you're leaving out a key element. This time it's the assumption $f(c), f(d)\in \{a, b\}$. In other words, _assuming_ that $f(0)$ and $f(t)$ are $0$ and $t$ (in some combination), strict monotonicity and bijectivity are equivalent.

Comment: Ah, okay. And I guess we only need to assume $f(0)=0$ for our $f$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You're mixing up the two results. One result is that if the function is strictly increasing, continuous and surjective, then $f(0) = 0, f(t) = t$. That's the one that you're asking about in your original post. The other result is that if $f$ is continuous, and $f(0)$ is either $0$ ot $t$, and $f(t)$ is either $0$ or $t$, then $f$ bijective $\iff$ $f$ strictly monotone. That's the one you linked to on proofwiki.

Comment: No, what I meant was that if $f$ is bijective and continuous and $f(0)=0$, then $f(t)=t$.